# Does the series of $\frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}$ converge to a function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, closed-form

So, I was resolving the equation $xy''+y'-y=0$ by calculating Frobenius series, and I got that the first linear independent solution is $y_1(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}$, which kind of looks like the power series for $e^x$, but I don't know what to do to the other $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Does this series converges to a function or should I just leave it indicated as the series?

Comment: Looks like a Bessel function to me.

Comment: @Lord so my ODE is a bessel equation? but what about  the $-y$? If a multiply by x again, i have $x^2y''+xy'-xy=0$, which looks like a bessel equation, but $-x$ doesn't look like $x^2-c^2$